# zsh configuration in tmux

Tags: zsh, tmux

I am using `tmux` and `zsh`.

When I am outside `tmux`, `zsh` is customized with some Manjaro settings, as per the `.zshrc`

```
# Use powerline
USE_POWERLINE="true"
# Source manjaro-zsh-configuration
if [[ -e /usr/share/zsh/manjaro-zsh-config ]]; then
  source /usr/share/zsh/manjaro-zsh-config
fi
# Use manjaro zsh prompt
if [[ -e /usr/share/zsh/manjaro-zsh-prompt ]]; then
  source /usr/share/zsh/manjaro-zsh-prompt
fi

# Use ssh-agent
if [[ -e /home/marcosh/ssh-agent.zsh ]]; then
  source /home/marcosh/ssh-agent.zsh
fi

source /usr/share/nvm/init-nvm.sh
```

When I am inside `tmux` though, the customizations are missing, eventhough it is using `zsh`. This is my `.tmux.conf`

```
set-option -g history-limit 50000

# sane scrolling
set-option -g mouse on
set -ga terminal-overrides ',xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'

# new pane on same folder
bind '"' split-window    -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind %   split-window -h -c "#{pane_current_path}"

# use zsh instead of bash
set -g default-command /usr/bin/zsh
```

What should I do to get the same `zsh` configuration both when inside and outside `tmux`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is tmux is not rendering the UTF-8 characters from the manjaro config properly.

To solve this use:

`tmux -u`

From the tmux manpage:

```
-u            Write UTF-8 output to the terminal even if the first 
              environment variable of LC_ALL, LC_CTYPE, or LANG that
              is set does not contain "UTF-8" or "UTF8".  This is
              equivalent to -T UTF-8.
```

Comment: Lifesaver. Works for me.